# json_encode array to json object with while loop

Tags: php, angularjs, arrays, json, loops

i'm fetch my data by while loop

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($do)) {
$data[] = array('id' => $row['id'],'email' => $row['email'],'phone' => 
    $row['num_phone'],'name' => $row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
print_r($data);
```

the output in console.log

```
[{"id":"1","email":"ali.@gmail.com","phone":"555555","name":"jjj"},
{"id":"4","email":"hh@yh.com","phone":"5555","name":"iii"},
{"id":"12","email":"ali@gmail.com","phone":"202","name":"twitter"},
{"id":"14","email":"exa@hotmail.com","phone":"949942","name":""}]
```

print_r function

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [email] => ali@gmail.com
            [phone] => 5999999
            [name] => a
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [email] => hh@yh.com
        [phone] => 5555
        [name] => iii
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [email] => ali@hotmail.com
        [phone] => 703
        [name] => dddd
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [email] => man@hotmail.com
        [phone] => 8757362
        [name] => new
    )
```

i want fetch to td but is not showing up

```
<tr ng-repeat="val in show">
<td>{{val.id}}</td>
<td>{{val.name}}</td>
<td>{{val.email}}</td>
<td>{{val.num_phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is the type of `show`? Is it `$data`? I think you should use `ng-repeat` once more above the `<tr>`.

Comment: That makes no sense, the data in the `print_r()` is completely different from the json. And there is no `num_phone` in either. Post the real code with the real output and don't use `print_r()` if you expect json back.

Comment: $http.post return data store in show py socpe

Comment: @jeroen the real code is to long 
 i have deleted some fields for a shortcut